# set title of tab in web browser

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control, tabcontrol

I am trying to make a web browser with multiple tabs. But now, I have a problem with the DocumentTitle for the name of the tabs.

The problem here is that the code to name the tab is performed before it loads the page. I tried to find a way to perform it after, but it doesn't work.

For example:

```
private void stackoverflowToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     ((WebBrowser) tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]) .Navigate("Http://www.stackoverflow.com/");
    Browser_Navigated(null, null);
}

void Browser_Navigated(object sender, WebBrowserNavigatedEventArgs e)
{
    tabControl1.SelectedTab.Text = ((WebBrowser)tabControl1.SelectedTab.Controls[0]).DocumentTitle;
}
```

Comment: You are using the wrong event, DocumentCompleted would be necessary to get the DocumentTitle.  Do note that you cannot use TabControl.SelectedTab in that event.  The user might have selected another tab.   And note that a document title is woefully unsuitable for a tab text, it is too long.

Answer (score 1):

The `WebBrowser` class exposes a `DocumentTitleChanged` event that you can use to update the tab title.